# Vue Inertia watcher in search input

Tags: vue.js, search, watch, page-refresh, inertiajs

[This is my search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBtb7.png)

Whenever I type any character the page always reload and I don't want that to happen.

```
watch(search, value => {
    Inertia.get('users',
        { search: value },
        { preserveState: true, replace: true }
    );
});
```

This is how I track my search box input by using watch in vue compositional api with inertia. But doesn't work.

```
Route::get('users', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Users/Index', [
        'users' => User::query()
            ->when(Request::input('search'), fn($query, $search) => $query
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            )
            ->paginate(10)
            ->withQueryString()
            ->through(
                fn($user) => [
                    'id' => $user->id,
                    'name' => $user->name,
                ]
            ),
        'filters' => Request::only(['search']),
    ]);
})
```

This is my server-side code I do pagination of 10 results and check if there's any query that is in search box exists.

My main objective is to make the page is not reloading when I search for something. It should wait until I finish typing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this forum looking for a solution to the same thing. Luckily I followed the documentation and found the right way to do it.  The only thing you have to do is to import ***router*** instead of ***Inertia***.

```
import { router } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

watch(search, (value) => {
    router.get("/users", { search: value }, { preserveState: true });
});
```

Greetings...

Comment: Thanks for the Great answer! This saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to monitor the search value and call a callback function every time the search value changes. When using the watch function with "replace: true", it indicates that the response from the server should replace the current page content instead of appending to it, thus lead to the full page reload every time the the search value changes.
To achieve your goal to prevent the page form reloading and only make the request after you finish typing, consider adding a delay mechanism.

```
let delayTimeout;

 watch(search, value => {
   clearTimeout(delayTimeout);

   delayTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
     Inertia.get('users', {
     search: value,
   }, {
     preserveState: true,
     replace: true,
   });
 }, 500); // Adjust the debounce delay (in milliseconds) as needed
})
```

Comment: It seems working when using delayTimeout but the browser is still doing full site reloading since I'm doing a single page application and using inertia. I want the result to dynamiclly render as I type or maybe delay a second and not doing a full site refresh. The browser should not refreshing when searching for something, it should render the result as I type in and the same way when removing each character.

Comment: Consider removing "replace: true" or initially fetching all the users when entering /users and filter it in client side  based on the search box input.